# Rendering data of ManyToMany relationship in templates in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to render the name of all the products in templates. How do I do that in dashboard.html in the code given below? It is simple in ForeignKey but i cannot figure it out in ManyToMany Relationship.Please help

**Models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY=(('INDOOR','Indoor'),('OUTDOOR','Outdoor'))

    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=20,
        choices=CATEGORY,
        blank=True,
        default='INDOOR',
        help_text='Item Category',)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS=(('PENDING','Pending'),('OUT FOR DELIVERY','Out For Delivery'),('DELIVERED','Delivered'))

    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    product=models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=20,
        choices=STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='PENDING',
        help_text='Delivery Status',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer.first_name
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    order=Order.objects.all()
    context={
    'order':order,
    }
    return render(request,'accounts/dashboard.html',context)
```

**dashboard.html**

```
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Date Orderd</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>

                      {%for i in order%}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{i}}</td>                              //in this line 
                    <td>{{i.date_created}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.status}}</td>
                    <td><button>Update</button> </td>
                    <td> <button>Update</button></td>

                </tr>
                    {%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the first model in Model.py is your Product class (you forgot to past the class name):

In your template replace:

```
<td>{{ i }}</td>
```

for

```
{% for product in order.product.all %}

<td>{{ product.name }}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey i did same but still not working.It shows blank                                                                                         
     ` {% for product in order.product.all %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                </tr>
                    {% endfor%}`